# Changing the "starting-width" for responsive design in Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive-design

i am currently building a wordpress website and having the problem, that I want to change the default/starting width for responsive design, but don't know where to find the media queries. Do I have to change the media queries or is there an other option to solve this problem? I would be very thankful for an answer.

Comment: Try css files in your themes folder

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ There are two ways to access the theme CSS which is what you're looking for _ The easiest is via the dashboard via 'Appearance -> Customise' _ The second is more difficult but it's more likely to be the one you need if you want to work with & alter defaults in media queries _ You'll need to access the theme folder in your Wordpress set-up which you'll find in 'wp-content -> themes' _ Look for 'style.css'